# How can I tell the difference between a preposition and a phrasal verb?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, phrasal-verbs

For example:

"I looked up the word."

Some people believe "up" is a particle but others believe that it's a preposition because it's followed by "the word".

I'm writing a document about prepositions(among other things) but I've been stuck on phrasal verbs for WEEKS.

Comment: Phrasal verb: *He looked up **the word skirt***. Preposition: *He looked up **her skirt***. The phrasal verb allows *He looked the word skirt up*, but you can't do that with the "preposition" version.

Comment: I think I understand. Using your logic, that means that the word "after" in "Look after your brother" is a preposition. Meanwhile, the word "down" in "He turned down my offer" is a particle. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm afraid not. From [Longman dictionary:](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/look-after#:~:text=From%20Longman%20Dictionary%20of%20Contemporary,look%20after%20the%20kids%20tomorrow.) *look after somebody/something - **phrasal verb**, especially British English*. I'm quite sure my two examples above *are* phrasal verb and preposition respectively, but ***to look after*** is definitely a phrasal verb meaning "tend, nurse", whereas the synonymous ***to care for*** looks to me like just a verb and a preposition. I don't really do "naming of the parts [of speech]" though.

Comment: Ugh, phrasal verbs are so... bothersome. No wonder my English teachers never mentioned them.

Comment: Here's one to really do your head in then! *I suggest you look up "phrasal verbs" in Wikipedia. Let me know if you've still got a problem, and I'll look after you.* But I'll decide later whether I'm offering to look in Wikipedia to see if I can understand what they say any better than you can, or if I'm offering to resolve all your problems in this area, with or without Wikipedia's help!

Comment: We've got a comedian here, ladies and gentlemen! But in all seriousness, I can't believe that I'm having so much trouble with this topic. It's simple at first glance but it's practically esoteric.

Comment: Okay, well if you figure it out, perhaps you can tell *me* what I was offering (or at least, what I *should* have been offering, syntactically / idiomatically speaking) in my preceding comment! :)

Comment: I'd say... Idiomatically, you meant "If you still don't understand phrasal verbs after checking Wikipedia, I'll take care of you. Literally, you meant "If you still don't understand phrasal verbs after checking Wikipedia, I'll check it myself."

Comment: I guess I should have said "I understand what phrasal verbs ARE, but I don't understand the mechanics".

Comment: I think you're missing the point I was trying to make. It would be easy to know which meaning was intended in "real" language (*spoken* English), because of where you'd place stress. But the *written* version as presented here is *inherently* ambiguous. Hence, since there's definitely no way to disambiguate that example, it stands to reason there ***cannot*** be a "comprehensive, exhaustive" set of rules telling you whether any given example is a phrasal verb or not.

Comment: Aw, shucks. I guess this particular topic will always be an enigma for me.

Comment: I do sympathise. For me as a native speaker, it's potentially useful to take on board @Jeff's dictum *If an object can follow the verb and precede the preposition, it is a phrasal verb.* But that's because I already know that if "the word skirt" is already a topic of conversation, I can say ***I'll look it up** [in the dictionary]*, but I *can't* say ***I'll look up it*** (which would only be valid if "it" has been conversationally established as referring to "her skirt", per the second example in my first comment). But that "rule of thumb" may not help *you*, as a non-native speaker!

Comment: I'm a native speaker lol. I think the reason why I'm having trouble with phrasal verbs is that different sites have different explanations. Would you say you agree with [this](http://blog.writeathome.com/index.php/2013/09/what-is-a-phrasal-verb/) site?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! I glanced at your link, and it looks sound to me. So if you look carefully at my previous comment, and specifically consider the case where you put the "object" ***after*** the phrasal verb *(I'll look the word up, I'll look up the word, I'll look it up, I'll look up it)*, you should hit a "parsing problem" with the 4th element in brackets there (because "it" can still refer to "the word" in #3, but not in #4). What I *think* that means is that you can often identify phrasal verbs specifically by how usage differs when you have a ***pronoun***.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Hopefully, I'll be able to put this topic behind me.

Answer (score 4):

Phrasal particles in particular can go at the end of sentences.

> I looked up the word.

> I looked the word up.

But you can't do this gracefully with a "real" preposition, like this:

> I climbed up the ladder.

> I climbed the ladder up. (fails)

Comment: 1: *Jack looked first. Then Jill **looked after him**, but she couldn't find it either.* 2: *Jack fell down and broke his crown. Then Jill **looked after him**.* One of those is a phrasal verb and the other isn't, but in neither case does it seem possible to move the preposition to the end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This one is easy if you are familiar with German separable verbs.

> Look it up

The verb here is “Look up,” a transitive, phrasal verb because you can insert the object between the two pieces of the verb and should do so if the object is a preposition.

> Look up it

The verb here is “look,” an intransitive, non-phrasal verb, which does not have an object, but is modified by an adverbial prepositional phrase.

If an object can follow the verb and precede the preposition, it is a phrasal verb.